# Adding to date in a while loop

Tags: php

I have a date that goes into a loop that the user specifies. The date will always come from the database formatted as a 'Y-m-d' string. I am aware that I can compare the strings directly as long as they are in that format, however, I have also tried using strtotime to convert the dates to compare them with no luck. I am trying to determine how many paycheck a user has before a payment is due

Here is what I have

```
    $due_date = '2016-12-13';

    //count paychecks set to zero and added to by loop
    $paychecks = 0;

    //users next paycheck ('Y-m-d' ALWAYS)
    $next_payday = $user['next_payday']; //equal to '2016-12-02'

    //how often they get paid (int)
    $frequency = 14;

    while(strtotime($next_payday) <= strtotime($due_date)){

        //next_payday equals 1480654800 when coming into the loop
        //due_date equals 1481605200 when coming into the loop

        //add 14 days to the date
        $next_payday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+" .$frequency." days"));;

        //add to paychecks
        $paychecks++;
    }
```

The problem is that the loop never stops. It keeps going and going.

Thanks for any help anyone can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, be sure to use strtotime to get integers (representing number of seconds since the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date))) for comparison and multiply your frequency of days by the number of seconds in a day (86400):

```
$due_date = strtotime('2016-12-25');

//count paychecks set to zero and added to by loop
$paychecks = 0;

//users next paycheck (unixtime for comparison)
$next_payday = strtotime($user['next_payday']);

//how often they get paid (int)
$frequency = 14;

while($next_payday <= $due_date){

    //add 14 days to the date
    $next_payday += ($frequency * 86400);

    //add to paychecks
    $paychecks++;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code. The loops keeps continuing even when using strtotime to convert the dates to int in while statement. I think its goofing with the adding 14 days to the current date

Comment: I missed the //add 14 days to the date
    $next_payday += ($frequency * 86400)

Comment: no worries - we've all been there - and sometimes we even have to go back for a visit hahaha